# How to extract an Apache FOP created PDF in C#?

Tags: c#, pdf, extract, apache-fop

I have a problem in my c# project.
I want to extract Apache FOP generated PDF files programatically without any 3rd party application.
I tried to use many libary like PDFBox, IKVM, PDF2Text, ITextSharp, PDFSharp to extract PDF files, but failed.
When i extract a FOP generated PDF to a text file, i get a lots of square symbols and other entangled characters.

My question is, how can i extract a FOP generated PDF file in C#?
Is there any library (written to C#), which can do that?

Thanks.

Comment: that depends massively on how the PDF is generated - FOP is not sufficient as a description... there are other apsects like: which fonts are used ? are the fonsts embedded ? which encoding is used (like unicode...) ?what character set (like CJK or RTL or...) ?

Comment: Used fonts: AllianzSans(Embedded) Encoding: Identity-H, AllianzSansLight (Embedded) Encoding: Identify-H, AllianzSans Bold (Embedded) Encoding: Indentity-H and Helvetica Encoding: Ansi. Character set is Left to Right.

Comment: and how do the extracted characters look exactly ?

Comment: Looks like: http://tinypic.com/r/2a7wg0p/7

Comment: what values are behing those squares (check with HEX editor!) ?

Comment: I was checked in a hex editor, but i didnt find any meaningful data. And i checked in an online ASCII85 decoder, because the filters in the PDF are ASCII85 and flate.

Comment: if you want this figured out you need to show the HEX values of some squares!

Comment: The hex editor shows me dots insteed of squares and the other characters are unchanged. The pdf file containing some text and numbers.

Comment: again: the HEXT editor shows you dots but also a HEX value for each dot - and that HEX value is what I need to know!

Comment: are you able to copy/paste text from the file(s) using Adobe Reader? could you share a link to one of such files?

Answer (score 0):

Fonts using Identity-H encoding use directly the glyph indexes for displaying the text on the page. These fonts require a ToUnicode entry in the font dictionary (in the PDF file) in order to support text extraction, otherwise it is not possible. Check the Apache FOP to see if it has a setting for including a ToUnicode entry in the font dictionary or for making the font extraction friendly.

Comment: I can not check the settings in FOP, because i have no any access to these configuration. I can only see the final result of the PDF. I know from the PDF properties, this is a FOP generated document. So i have some chance to extract?

Comment: In this situation you have no chance to extract the text.